# Comment dire "I am sick and will rest at home"?

Tags: expressions

J'aimerais savoir la meilleure façon de dire que "I will rest at home" pour une maladie.

Je me demande si c'est:

> - je vais reposer à la maison;
> - je vais me reposer à la maison

ou

> - je repose à la maison

Est-ce que ça peut avoir des significations différentes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two *reposer* verbs in French. The first one means ***re***-poser, i.e. *poser ne nouveau*, and the second one relates to ***repos*** and ***pause*** (break) and used to be written *repauser* in early French.

The first one is always transitive so is excluded in the first and third attempts.

Examples of its usage can be:

> *Je vais reposer du carrelage à la maison.*

I'm going to lay tiles again in my home.

> *Je vais reposer la question à mon voisin.*

I'm going to ask the question again to my neighbor.

The second *reposer* verb matches *rest*.

> *Je repose à la maison*

This used to be possible in the past but is no more used in modern French, outside archaic regional usage. It might still be heard in Provence for example. Otherwise, it would have the unlikely meaning:

> I rest (in peace) at home (i.e. I'm dead.)

Here is a non reflexive way to use *reposer* that has a meaning closer to your English sentence:

> *Je vais reposer mes yeux à la maison*:

I'm going to rest my eyes at home.

> *Je vais me reposer à la maison*:

I'm going to have a rest at home.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and all explanation. That is what I thought I heard in the past, but I was not very sure. If it is not reflexive, it means that I died. I use it indistinctly one or another, people around me understand me, but they don't correct me. That is a huge problem, because people think I am tarzan as I moved to a French city! Time to seek help from here!!! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Tout simplement :

> Je suis malade et je vais me reposer à la maison.

Comment: merci pour la réponse. J'aimerais clarifier que je suis déjà chez moi. Je suis jamais parti le matin, puis mettons ça va être juste pour aujourd'hui. Je viens de regarder une video sur Youtube d'un joeur de football, puis il dissait comme ta réponse. J'ai pensé que c'est pour un période d'inactivité longue.

Comment: Tu pourrais dire aussi : « Je suis malade et je me repose à la maison. »

Comment: Merci encore. Donc, pense tu que toutes les phrases ont la même signification?

Comment: @MaximusDecimus Attention :-)! C'est **penses-tu**. Avec trait d'union.

Comment: @MaximusDecimus: La deuxième phrase est correcte, les deux autres incorrectes. Il faut utiliser le verbe pronominal **se** reposer.

Answer (score 1):

The second guess does it: "je vais me reposer à la maison.". However, instead of "à la maison" you can say "chez moi" if you speak to people you don't know well, the more formal register of "chez moi" is preferable.